# Sending only changed fields to PHP back end from jtable javascript

Tags: javascript, web, jtable

I'm trying to find a clean way to send only the changed fields in the AJAX call from a Javascript JTable.  The default updateAction sends all current values from the edit form in the POST header whether they have been changed or not.

I would prefer to run a SQL 'update' statement in the PHP back end with only the values that were modified and must be updated.  I have been unsuccessful in finding a solution on jtable.org documentation or forums.

Thanks in advance for any help.